# Does creating account with geth command "geth account new" make a new key store holder?

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

There are multiple ways of creating a ethereum account through geth.

- `geth account new`
- `newAcc, _ := am.NewAccount("Creation password");` by importing `import "github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/accounts"`

**Does `geth account new` also create a new Keystore holder for the new account? And if it does where is it store?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the command `geth account new` generates a new keystore.

It's default location is `/home/<username>/.ethereum`.

You can specify the location using the `--datadir` option.

`geth account new --datadir <your-custom-location>`

Hope this helps.